# Deleting Selected Files from Checked List Box in c# Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, listbox

I want to delete file ( real files from HDD) from checkedlistbox.
I'm gonna use Files.Delete("x");
In the x place I want to put the item that the user checked in the checkedlistbox.
I don't know how to get the checked values from the checkedlistbox.

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.zip");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

ListBox1 is a checkedlistbox. I want to scan the zip files from C:/ and show them up in the listbox and it works. If i want to delete them, I need to go to the File Explorer to delete. I want to delete them using the application. So please help me out...

Comment: You can get the files from the drive, you know how to delete files as well. What exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the CheckedItems property of your CheckedListBox

```
foreach (var item in lb.CheckedItems)
{
    File.Delete((string)item);
}
```

Note that you can cast item to a string because you originally put a string in the Items collection.

Comment: I'm new to c# programming. and it's still not working. Do i need to paste that code in my Delete Button?

Comment: It dosen't delete that file

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line `File.Delete((string)item);`  Does the debugger stop there?  Mouse over item.  What value does it have?

Comment: I can only find the name in the value(name of a selected item) I can't find its file location or anything.